# 動作 as opposed to 作用

Tags: vocabulary, linguistics

The linguistics text I’m reading has a sentence with this fragment: 「動詞の表す動作・作用が[…]」。 Consulting dictionaries just made me more confused; what’s the contrast between the two in this context? “Action” vs. “effect”?

Comment: perhaps the [...] in your question could provide more contextual clues?

Comment: Here you go:

「金田一春彦は動詞の表す動作・作用が時間的にどのように捉えられているかによって、次の4類が立てられることを説いた。」

The title (and topic) is 『アスペクトによる動詞の分類』.

Comment: It is often stated that in the Japanese grammar, verbs signify 動作, 作用, and 存在.  (There are variations of this statement with more options or less.)  But I do not know why 動作 and 作用 are often both listed.  In general, 動作 (motion, workings) and 作用 (action, effect) mean different things, but I do not know which verbs describe 作用 without describing 動作.

Comment: Have you seen an answer to this question here: http://okwave.jp/qa/q2439819.html ?  I'll try to write more about it later if you are still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

動詞 in Japanese can represent 3 different things, 動作、作用 and 存在.
An example will be easier to understand.

```
動作：
道を歩く
```

歩く is categorized as 動作をあらわす動詞, because when you walk, you move your legs, in other words "movement" or "action".

```
作用：
壁に絵をかける
```

かける is categorized as 作用を表す動詞, here 壁にかける is having an "effect" on the wall.

```
存在：
机に本がある
```

ある is categorized as 存在を表す動詞, here ある indicates "existence".

So back to your question, "動作" doesn't directly place any influence on other "things" whereas "作用" directly "effects" other things.